# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 93 path $.details[0].messages

Tags: android, json, gson

I have this following class

```
public class InstallationRequest {


@SerializedName("install_id")
@Expose
private String installId;
@SerializedName("ref_no")
@Expose
private String refNo;
@SerializedName("billing_msn")
@Expose
private String existingSrNo;
@SerializedName("meter_msn")
@Expose
private String smartMsn;
@SerializedName("site_issues")
@Expose
private String siteIssue;
@SerializedName("istallation_status")
@Expose
private String installStatus;
@SerializedName("latitude")
@Expose
private String latitude;
@SerializedName("longitude")
@Expose
private String longitude;
@SerializedName("comm_status")
@Expose
private String commStatus;
@SerializedName("so_person_name")
@Expose
private String personName;
@SerializedName("so_phone_number")
@Expose
private String personPhone;
@SerializedName("so_person_designation")
@Expose
private String personPhoneDesig;
@SerializedName("customer_id")
@Expose
private String customerId;
@SerializedName("consumer_name")
@Expose
private String consumerName;
@SerializedName("consumer_address")
@Expose
private String consumerAddress;
@SerializedName("tarrif")
@Expose
private String tarrif;
@SerializedName("s_load")
@Expose
private String sLoad;
@SerializedName("auth_key")
@Expose
private String authKey;
@SerializedName("imsi_no")
@Expose
private String imsiNo;
@SerializedName("ct_ratio")
@Expose
private String ctRatio;
@SerializedName("old_meter_power")
@Expose
private String oldMeterPower;
@SerializedName("old_meter_reactive_power")
@Expose
private String oldMeterReactivePower;
@SerializedName("new_meter_power")
@Expose
private String newMeterPower;
@SerializedName("new_meter_reactive_power")
@Expose
private String newMeterReactivePower;
@SerializedName("created_date")
@Expose
private String createdDate;
@SerializedName("site_images_name")
@Expose
private List<ImageName> siteImagesName = null;
@SerializedName("doc_images_name")
@Expose
private List<ImageName> docImagesName = null;

public String getInstallId() {
    return installId;
}

public void setInstallId(String installId) {
    this.installId = installId;
}

public String getRefNo() {
    return refNo;
}

public void setRefNo(String refNo) {
    this.refNo = refNo;
}

public String getExistingSrNo() {
    return existingSrNo;
}

public void setExistingSrNo(String existingSrNo) {
    this.existingSrNo = existingSrNo;
}

public String getSmartMsn() {
    return smartMsn;
}

public void setSmartMsn(String smartMsn) {
    this.smartMsn = smartMsn;
}

public String getSiteIssue() {
    return siteIssue;
}

public void setSiteIssue(String siteIssue) {
    this.siteIssue = siteIssue;
}

public String getInstallStatus() {
    return installStatus;
}

public void setInstallStatus(String installStatus) {
    this.installStatus = installStatus;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getCommStatus() {
    return commStatus;
}

public void setCommStatus(String commStatus) {
    this.commStatus = commStatus;
}

public String getPersonName() {
    return personName;
}

public void setPersonName(String personName) {
    this.personName = personName;
}

public String getPersonPhone() {
    return personPhone;
}

public void setPersonPhone(String personPhone) {
    this.personPhone = personPhone;
}

public String getPersonPhoneDesig() {
    return personPhoneDesig;
}

public void setPersonPhoneDesig(String personPhoneDesig) {
    this.personPhoneDesig = personPhoneDesig;
}

public String getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public String getConsumerName() {
    return consumerName;
}

public void setConsumerName(String consumerName) {
    this.consumerName = consumerName;
}

public String getConsumerAddress() {
    return consumerAddress;
}

public void setConsumerAddress(String consumerAddress) {
    this.consumerAddress = consumerAddress;
}

public String getTarrif() {
    return tarrif;
}

public void setTarrif(String tarrif) {
    this.tarrif = tarrif;
}

public String getSLoad() {
    return sLoad;
}

public void setSLoad(String sLoad) {
    this.sLoad = sLoad;
}

public String getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public List<ImageName> getSiteImagesName() {
    return siteImagesName;
}

public void setSiteImagesName(List<ImageName> siteImagesName) {
    this.siteImagesName = siteImagesName;
}

public List<ImageName> getDocImagesName() {
    return docImagesName;
}

public void setDocImagesName(List<ImageName> docImagesName) {
    this.docImagesName = docImagesName;
}

public InstallationRequest(InstallationDetails installationDetails,List<ImageName> siteImagesName,List<ImageName> docImagesName) {

    this.refNo = installationDetails.getReferenceNo();
    this.smartMsn = installationDetails.getMsn();
    this.existingSrNo = installationDetails.getExistingSrNo();
    this.latitude = installationDetails.getLatitude();
    this.longitude = installationDetails.getLongitude();
    this.tarrif = installationDetails.getTarrif();
    this.sLoad = installationDetails.getsLoad();
    this.personName = installationDetails.getPersonName();
    this.personPhone = installationDetails.getPersonPhone();
    this.personPhoneDesig = installationDetails.getPersonPhoneDesig();
    this.customerId = installationDetails.getCustomerId();
    this.installStatus = installationDetails.getInstallStatus();
    this.siteIssue = installationDetails.getSiteIssue();
    this.installId = installationDetails.getInstallId();
    this.createdDate = installationDetails.getCreatedDate();
    this.consumerName = installationDetails.getConsumerName();
    this.consumerAddress = installationDetails.getConsumerAddress();
    this.commStatus= installationDetails.getCommStatus();

    this.authKey = installationDetails.getUserAuthKey();
    this.imsiNo = installationDetails.getIMSI_NO();
    //this.ctRatio = installationDetails.getCT_RATIO();
    this.oldMeterPower = installationDetails.getOldMeterPower();
    this.oldMeterReactivePower = installationDetails.getOldMeterReactivePower();
    this.newMeterPower = installationDetails.getNewMeterPower();
    this.newMeterReactivePower = installationDetails.getNewMeterReactivePower();

    this.siteImagesName = siteImagesName;
    this.docImagesName = docImagesName;
    Log.d("zed",createdDate);
}
}
```

And a retrofit call that save the data in to the DB.

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<ApiResponse.Detail> details = response.body().getDetails();
                        for (ApiResponse.Detail d :
                                details) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "response is " + d.getStatus());
                            installManager.updateStatus(d.getInstallId(), d.getStatus());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG,"internal server error");
                        for (InstallationDetails detail :
                                mInstallationDetailsArrayList) {
                            installManager.updateStatus(detail.getInstallId(), Constants.INSTALLATION_CLOSE);
                        }
                    }
                    Intent broadcastSyc = new Intent();
                    broadcastSyc.setAction(Common.GetSyncDataAction());
                    broadcastSyc.putExtra("STATUS", true);
                    mContext.sendBroadcast(broadcastSyc);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"server connection failed");
                    for (InstallationDetails detail :
                            mInstallationDetailsArrayList) {
                        installManager.updateStatus(detail.getInstallId(), Constants.INSTALLATION_CLOSE);
                    }
                    Intent broadcastSyc = new Intent();
                    broadcastSyc.setAction(Common.GetSyncDataAction());
                    broadcastSyc.putExtra("STATUS", true);
                    mContext.sendBroadcast(broadcastSyc);
                }
            });
```

When I try to upload the data to the server it give me bellow error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 93 path $.details[0].messages

The above error shows on `public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t)`

I have tried to send the request VIA postman.

```
{
"ref_no": "19373150570602U",
"meter_msn"      :"002999000199",
"billing_msn" : "183673" ,
"latitude": "31.4384412",
"longitude": "74.2749083",
"tarrif": "01",
"s_load": "5",
"so_person_name" : "",
"so_phone_number" : "",
"so_person_designation" : "",
"customer_id" :"37030282250",
"imsi_no":"",
"istallation_status": "Installed",
"site_issues" : "No hand-over person",
"install_id" : "19373150570602U_1512883614",
"created_date": "2017-12-10 10:26:54",
"consumer_name": "M.SC.P.O BEAT 31 OFFICE NEAR SINDH SEED COORPORATION 
 SAKRAND",
"consumer_address" :"M.SC.P.O BEAT 31 OFFICE NEAR SINDH SEED COORPORATION 
 SAKRAND",
"comm_status" : "Verified",
"auth_key": "",
"ct_ratio": "200",
"old_meter_power": "",
"old_meter_reactive_power": "",
"new_meter_power": "",
"new_meter_reactive_power": "",
"site_images_name" : ["19373150570602U_1512883614_site_1.jpg"],
"doc_images_name" : []
}
```

In postman I am getting below error

> {
>       "name": "PHP Notice",
>       "message": "Trying to get property of non-object",
>       "code": 8,
>       "type": "yii\base\ErrorException",
>       "file": "E:\xampp\htdocs\common\models\Installations.php",
>       "line": 116,
>       "stack-trace": [
>           "#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\common\models\Installations.php(116): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'E:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 116, Array)",
>           "#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\api\modules\v1\controllers\InstallationController.php(29): common\models\Installations::saveAll(Object(stdClass))",
>           "#2 [internal function]: api\modules\v1\controllers\InstallationController->actionAddnew()",
>           "#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
>           "#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)",
>           "#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('addnew', Array)",
>           "#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('v1/installation...', Array)",
>           "#7 E:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))",
>           "#8 E:\xampp\htdocs\api\web\index.php(35): yii\base\Application->run()",
>           "#9 {main}"
>       ]
>   }

While looking into `line # 116` in my `Yii2` code the exception comes at below point

```
if (Installations::find()->where(['ref_no' => $input->ref_no])->exists()) {
            $arr_status[] = ['install_id' => $input->install_id, 'status' => 2, 'messages' => "Ref # Already exists"];
            continue;
        }
```

I don't know why the exception is coming as it was working a day before and I haven't change the code a bit

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is missing an `ApiResponse` class where the error starts

Comment: @cricket_007 I have mentioned it the error starts at `public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t)`

Comment: No, no. You've shown an `InstallationRequest` class. Retrofit is complaining about the `ApiResponse` class. Please edit your question to show it

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with ImageName Object.

```
@SerializedName("site_images_name")
@Expose
private List<String> siteImagesName = null;
@SerializedName("doc_images_name")
@Expose
private List<String> docImagesName = null;
```

Try to do this. Or Make changes in ImageName put a String member in that.

Comment: The error mentions a `messages` key, nothing about images

Comment: messages key is not mentioned i guess